# Partimento does not exist on this site?

Tags: discussion

That's what the box told me when I went looking for a Partimento tag. To me, the new scholarship around partimento is the most interesting things to appear in "classical" music since.....Wagner. It is highly subversive to the established order, undermining the provenance of Roman Numerals, and championing teaching structured improvisation from the earliest days....no interest? Can we have a tag?

Comment: Until there are questions, there is no need for a tag.

Comment: @PiedPiper It seems like there are a number of questions (9) that at least mention "partimento": https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q="partimento"+is%3Aquestion

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Okay, then we need the tag

Comment: With only 9 questions, is a new tag necessary? I'm fairly inactive on this SE but am on SO every day, and over there we would likely just direct users to a parent-category tag (in this case, composition or improvisation) unless/until related questions saw an uptick.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace But these 9 results include this meta question, so it is really only 8, and of these only 6 are specifically about _partimento_ (with one question literally just being "what is partimento?"). This is not really a lot and might not justify a dedicated tag, on the other hand we do have a tag for "archeterie" with a total of 5 questions, one of which is about making an ebow which does not really belong there.

Comment: @Charlie_Webster It's up to you to make a stronger case that there is a *need* for this proposed tag.  You should update this question with some reasons why the tags such as [figured-bass] and [lead-sheets] aren't sufficient for questions about partimento.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might be looking for the [lead-sheets](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lead-sheets) tag. Lead sheets are pieces written out as melody and chord symbols that are often used by pop or jazz musicians as a basis for playing a song and improvising.

Older styles of partimenti would be covered by [figured-bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figured-bass).